# Complex type declaration with an anonymous profile as a parameter

Tags: c, function-pointers

I read one Russian book about c-programming. I ran into a question. There is the function with such type:

```
int (*replace_f(int (*func)(int, int)))(int, int)
```

This function gets a pointer of function with type "int (int, int)" and returns a pointer of the function with the same type. One important note, neither of the two identifiers(replace_f,func) wasn't declared anywhere in the code before.
It's a correct declare and I understand it.  But then, the author claims if we need to declare the type pointer to the early function we have to declare as:

```
int (*(*ptr_replace)(int ( * )(int, int)))(int, int);
not as 
int (*(*ptr_replace)(int ( *func )(int, int)))(int, int);
or
int (*(*ptr_replace)(int ( *any_other_identifier )(int, int)))(int, int);
```

In other words, we definitely have to write an anonymous type  **int(*)(int, int))**
But any of the cases is working and compiling successfully.
He claims that it's not available to use two or more identifiers in the type declaration. Why does it work then?

Comment: `of function with profile "int (int, int)"` I think you mean ["type"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type), probably translation thing, it's called "type", not "profile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `int (*replace_f(int (*func)(int, int)))(int, int);`, the declaration of `func` has *function prototype scope* because it appears inside a function declaration. So this declaration declares two identifiers, `replace_f` and `func`, but the scope of `func` ends at the end of the function declaration.

That makes `func` useless in this case. There are situations where an identifier in function prototype scope is useful, such as `void foo(int x, int y, float a[x][y]);`, where `x` and `y` are used to describe the dimensions of `a`.

> But then, the author claims if we need to declare the type pointer to the early function we have to declare as: … not as …

This is incorrect. You can declare `ptr_replace` in any of the three ways shown.

> He claims that it's not available to use two or more identifiers in the type declaration. Why does it work then?

It does work to declare `replace_f`. It does not work to declare `func` or `any_other_identifier`. So perhaps the original text meant something like this?

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I understood right, the second and third declaration is syntactically correct. But declaring the second identifier is pointless for the reason of inability to use it in the future. Right?

Comment: Yes, right, except it serves a good documentation purpose. `int func(unsigned size_of_an array, char *pointer_to_data, int operation_mode);` is easier to read then `int func(unsigned, char*, int);`